# Dismiss a UIViewController without dismissing an alert on top of it

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController that presents a UIAlertController. I would like the UIAlertController to dismiss itself while still allowing the UIAlertController to stay on top.

Here's the code to dismiss:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

I'll omit the code for UIAlertController, but I'm using this code to present:

```
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I'm looking for a solution that can be contained within my single UIViewController subclass.

Comment: can u explain "UIAlertController to dismiss itself while still allowing the UIAlertController to stay on top" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your scenario is like this:
A_ViewController pushed B_ViewController, B_ViewController presented alertController at some circumstances. Now you're at B_ViewController and want to dismiss itself without the alert disappear,right? 
If I got this right,I don't think this gonna work. Because alert depends on B_ViewController, if B is gone, so did alert.
Here is my thought:
A_ViewController pushed B_ViewController, now we're at B, at some circumstances there should be an alert being presented,instead of letting B present the alert, we could let A present the alert(We could use delegate method to tell A to present an alert). And now, B and alert are independent,B gone,alert stays.
I hope this would help.